# If a column value matches between 2 rows, keep the newer row with a value in a third column based on a condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
    id    time     type
     1      t1     create
     1      t2     modify
     2      t3     modify
     2      t4     deploy
     3      t5     delete
```

The time is increasing with t2 newer than t1, t3 new than t2, etc.  If there is a modify in type, then there will be another row with a type that is not modify.  Otherwise, there will be only one row with a type other than modify.  For the 2 rows that contain a modify, I want to keep whichever row is new (larger tn) but I want the value in type that is not modify.  So, I want the table above to be changed to the following table:

```
   id.   time.    type
   1.     t2.     create
   2.     t4.     deploy
   3.     t5.     delete
```

Where the ids match I want to keep the row with the newest time with the type that is not
modify.  In other words, if there is an id without a modify, then there will be one row and I want to keep it.  If there is a modify, then there will be another row with the same id.  I want to keep whichever row is the newer of the pair, and if the modify is newer, I want to overwrite the type of modify with the value that is in the type column of the older row.

I know how to keep the newer row with the same id but I don't know how to ensure that if the non-modify type is older, that the non-modify type value is copied into the type field replacing the the value modify in the newer row and keeping the newer row and then dropping the older row.  Can someone show me how to do this?

This is all I have been able to come up with:
df.loc[df.groupby('id')['time'].idxmax(), type != modify]

It looks like I can simplify my question down to:

```
  id.   time.   type
   1     t1    create
   1     t2    modify
`''

Based on the previous df, I want to produce the following:
```

```
id.   time.    type
 1     t2     create
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, for each grouping of ID- you want to find:

1. What is the latest `time` value. I suspect in reality these are something like timestamps, but in this example they're simple strings.
2. What is the `type` value that is NOT modify

We can use `.groupby` to accomplish both of these, but the most effective solution will be to use `.groupby` to solve ①, and then use a simple filter for ②.

EDIT: `.drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')` will also work to answer ① and will probably be faster than `.groupby(...).last()`

```py
out = (
    df.groupby('id')[['time']].last()
    .assign(
        type=df.set_index('id').loc[lambda d: d['type'] != 'modify', 'type']
    )
)

print(out)
   time    type
id             
1    t2  create
2    t4  deploy
3    t5  delete
```

Alternatively, if you're not concerned with the efficacy of the computation you can use a `.groupby` with a lambda to solve ② instead.

```py
out = (
    df.groupby('id')
    .agg(
        time=('time', 'last'), 
        type=('type', lambda s: s.loc[s != 'modify'])
    )
)

print(out)
   time    type
id             
1    t2  create
2    t4  deploy
3    t5  delete
```

Comment: I was able to get the second one to work and it gave me the exact results I want.  Thanks!  I wasn't able to get the first one to work,   When I ran the original first one I get: type error: "string indices must be integers". and I was not able to solve it with several different combinations of parenthesis.  Then when I ran it with: ."drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')... It did run but I got NaN for the type on the last row when there wasn't a pair.

Comment: I've fixed the first example for you- messed up the parentheses when I copy/patesd.

For the `drop_duplicates`, you'll need to `.set_index('id')` after you use `.drop_duplicates`. I can write up some extra code when I have a moment.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The second one is working well though I haven't been able to try it yet under load.  I am looking forward to trying the first 2. as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could first remove the "modify", then keep the last row per group:

```
df.loc[df['type'].ne('modify')].drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
```

Output:

```
   id time    type
0   1   t1  create
3   2   t4  deploy
4   3   t5  delete
```

##### updating the time based on "modify"

```
m = df['type'].eq('modify')

out = (df.assign(time=df['time'].where(m)
                      .groupby(df['id']).bfill()
                      .fillna(df['time'])
                )
         .loc[~m]
         .drop_duplicates(subset=['id'], keep='last')
      )
```

Output:

```
   id time    type
0   1   t2  create
3   2   t4  deploy
4   3   t5  delete
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it clearly enough.  This looks close, but I want the first row to have time t2 not t1.  That's what I don't know how to do.  If the row has modify and its the newer row, I want to replace the type field with the type value from the older row.  In this case update the row with t2 with create.

Comment: One thing that I think will work is if there is a row with modify and another with not modify  I could copy what ever is in the row that does not have the modify and replace modify and then take the newer of the two rows?

Comment: If I have a row with id=1, time=t1, type=create and a paired row with id=1, time=t2, type = modify then I want to have:  id=1, time=t2, type=create.  How can I do that?

Comment: If there is a row with type modify, then I want to update it from the type field of the
other row with the same id.  Then I will keep the one with the newest time.   I actually only need to do the copy of the type field if the modify is newer, but it is ok to make the copy whether the modify is newer or older.  I will get the correct result when I drop the older one.

Comment: @RobertLuse that wasn't clear indeed, see my updated answer ;)

Comment: It would be interesting to see how this generalizes (e.g. when you have several "modified" per id)